# Content going out of desired div in an Android app

Tags: android, css

I am working on an Android app. When I slide the screen right I get a blank grey screen and when I slide the screen left I again get a blank screen with some of my content on it. I have attached pictures of the problem to better understand it.
I want to solve this problem via CSS if possible.

Second:
[image: second]

First:
[image: first]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example with your current css code. You can use overflow hidden for example but it depends on the rest of the code what will solve your problem

Comment: #sdbr{
    position: relative;
    display: none!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;

  }
  #sdbr2{
    position:relative;
    display: none!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: this is my code to remove overflow but its not working

Comment: Change `overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden;` to: `overflow:hidden;`